# parity command failes due to missing c++ libs

Tags: parity

Today I decided to switch to parity but after (successfully) installing I got the following after typing 'parity':

```
parity: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by parity)
parity: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by parity)
parity: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by parity)
```

Answer (score 2):

if running centos/RH Execute the following steps to solve it:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ldconfig
```

if it doesn't work have a look at the solution proposed here :
https://github.com/cdr/code-server/issues/347